# Can a class containing a function pointer be used as a non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, non-type

Consider the following class `S` containing a function pointer, and a `constexpr` object `s` of that class initialized with a lambda:

```
struct S 
{ 
    void (*f) (); 
};

constexpr S s { []{} };
```

Now if I write a template `X` with a non-type template parameter of type `S`, and instantiate it over `s` like this:

```
template<S> struct X {};
using x = X<s>;
```

clang compiles the code, but gcc complains with:

```
error: '<lambda()>::_FUN' is not a valid template argument of type 'void (*)()' because '<lambda()>::_FUN' is not a variable
using x = X<s>;
             ^
```

Here's the [program](https://godbolt.org/z/MMv1hh).

The code seems fine to me, and I'm not sure what the error message is referring to. So is this code valid?

Note that both compilers accept the code if `X` instead has a non-type template parameter of reference type to `S`, like this:

```
template<S const &> struct X {};
```

---

This question was inspired by another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654827).

Comment: Seems likely to be a variant of [this GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83258).

Comment: @DavisHerring I think this is a different bug. This error message explicitly mentions "is not a variable".

Comment: @DavisHerring It does look related, and there are a number of posts about linkage issues with gcc, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213997). The diagnostic seems different though, but if it is related, maybe that bug report should be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is valid.

[[temp.arg.nontype]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2.sentence-1):

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be a converted constant expression ([expr.const]) of the type of the *template-parameter*.

[[expr.const]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#10):

> A *converted constant expression* of type `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to type `T`, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only [...]

(There's no implicit conversion in this case.)

[[expr.const]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#11):

> A constant expression is [...] or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - if the value is an object of class type, each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression,
> - if the value is of pointer type, it contains [...] the address of a non-immediate function [...],
> - if the value is of pointer-to-member-function type, [...],
> - if the value is an object of class or array type, each subobject satisfies these constraints for the value.
>
> An entity is a *permitted result of a constant expression* if [...] or if it is a non-immediate function.

(All functions are non-immediate except for the `consteval` ones. [[dcl.constexpr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#2.sentence-2))

Therefore, `s` is a valid converted constant expression of type `S`. In addition, it is not subject to [[temp.arg.nontype]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#3) (which only applies to pointer/reference to objects).

That is, `s` is a valid template argument.

---

> I'm not sure what the error message is referring to

It's nonsense.

The error is emitted from [`invalid_tparm_referent_p`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/444655b6f02605ae936426a14ba527795795587b/gcc/cp/pt.c#L6995) inside GCC. It was extracted from code for handling pointer to object type when class non-type template paramter was implemented ([4be5c72](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/4be5c72cf3ea3ee98a97ac2e53d21122ad224b10)). Apparently, the implementer forgot to update this function to account for the pointer-to-function case.

I've reported the bug as https://gcc.gnu.org/PR97700.

Comment: Yes, this looks right. Thanks for filing the bug, I'll accept the answer as soon as the bug is confirmed.